# What is a proper word for no-matter-how-many?

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms

Just like we use *whatever* for *no-matter-what*, what is an appropriate word for *no-matter-how-many*?

Comment: Would two words be acceptable? I would personally use "however many".

Comment: Or, if three words would be acceptable: "any number of".

Comment: or "regardless of the number of"

Comment: It's increasingly common even in ordinary conversational contexts to hear people use **n** (sometimes **x**), as in [Suppose you have n people...](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22you+have+n+people%22)

Comment: It's a little bit of a misaligned analogy. We have who(m), what, when, where, how, and why, and we have who(m)ever, whatever, whenever, however and even whyever (it's uncommon, but it's there). "How many" is narrowing the question, so like @AndyT suggests, "however many" narrows the response appropriately. If we had "whump" for "how many", I bet we would have whumpever, but we don't.

Comment: I suppose you could use _whatever_ itself, and the meaning will be understood from context.

Answer (score 1):

An arbitrary number of. But it looks a little scientific, like from a math book.